# How to set Java version for SBT

Tags: java, scala, sbt, java-15

I am trying to run a scala program, in which there are errors with Java 16. My colleague is using Java 15, and all is fine. When i type `java -version` in my terminal it says i am using Java 15. However, when i run `sbt run -v`, it says it is using Java 16, and thus the program throws errors.

I am seeing people talk about this `sbt-extra` thing, but not a whole lot of explanation on how to use it. I do not even have Java 16 installed on my Mac, so I am really confused as to why SBT says this.

Comment: **sbt** should just uses what is on the `JAVA_HOME` If you are sure you do not have **Java 16** installed then it shouldn't use that, **sbt** doesn't download **JDKs**.

Comment: If it is using Java 16 then its definitely installed somewhere. Check your java installation folder which can be found by following `which java`. You can set `JAVA_HOME` or use `sbt -java-home <path/to/jdk>` to use specific jdk.

Comment: SET JAVA_HOME=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-16.0.1 <next line>
sbt

Answer (score 5):

Add this to `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` (depending on shell preferences/OS), or just run this before running `sbt` in a terminal:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home
```

**It's better though** to do this per-sbt project via `build.sbt` as per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76456295/1586965

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to do this via the `build.sbt` file so then it's specific to just that project not your entire local environment.  I.e. add the following to `build.sbt`:

```
  javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "11", "-target", "11")
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle your installed jvms you can use [Jenv](http://%20https://www.jenv.be/).

To install jenv:

```
git clone https://github.com/jenv/jenv.git ~/.jenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

echo 'eval "$(jenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Then, you can add your intalled jvms. In Mac, if you have installed them via **brew** you can find those in: ***/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines***.

Then add them to jenv:

```
jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home 
jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
```

You can see the available jvms in jenv:

[image: jenv_versions]

you can set the default jvm with the command:

```
jenv global 1.8.0.121
```

Then, execute sbt in some of your projects and you should see that jvm as the jvm that sbt is using.

Comment: I did not know about this thing, Its great tool

Comment: I'd like to use [jabba](https://github.com/shyiko/jabba). I think that is very similar to jenv at this point..

Answer (score 1):

Another option which worked for me is to add the version of java you want to be used to the front of your terminal PATH environment variable. Since I used homebrew to install openjdk, I used the path they suggested resulting in the following path to use openjdk version 11.

```
export PATH="usr/local/opt/openjdk@11/bin:$PATH"
```

Note - the openjdk path I used I think is just the homebrew symlink to the actual java installation which is in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines. You could probably just use that actual path but I didn't test it.

Comment: I do believe that setting the JAVA_HOME variable is a better option. I just wanted to give this option in case other things don't work for someone.